# Animated heatmap from dictionary of Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, gif

I would like to plot an animated heatmap from a group of DataFrames (for example saved in a dictionary), either as gif or a movie.

For example, say I have the following collection of DFs. I can display all of them one after the other. But I would like to have them all being shown in the same figure in the same way as a GIF is shown (a loop of the heatmaps).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataframe_collection = {}

for i in range(5):
    dataframe_collection[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)))

    # Here within the same loop just for brevity
    sns.heatmap(dataframe_collection[i])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What library are you using for the image visualization

Comment: For visualizing a single DF, I usually use pandas style.background_gradient(). Seaborn or matplotlib would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to first create separate png images, and then use a software such as ImageMagick to convert them to an animated gif.

Example to create the png's:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dataframe_collection = {}
for i in range(5):
    dataframe_collection[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)))
    #plt.pcolor(dataframe_collection[i])
    sns.heatmap(dataframe_collection[i])
    plt.gca().set_ylim(0, len(dataframe_collection[i])) #avoiding problem with axes
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(f'dataframe_{i}.png')
```

After installing [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) the following shell command creates a gif. If the defaults are not satisfying, use the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/reference.html) to explore the many options.

`convert.exe -delay 20 -loop 0 dataframe_*.png dataframes.gif`

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712669/exporting-animated-gif-using-matplotlib) about creating animations and an animated gif inside matplotlib.

Note that Seaborn's heatmap also has some features such as `sns.heatmap(dataframe_collection[i], annot=True)`.

If you're unable to use ImageMagick, you could show a video by quickly displaying single png files, simulating a video.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486961/animated-image-with-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780877/frame-by-frame-animation-with-javascript) post contain more explanations and example code. Especially the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9487083/12046409) looks promising.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using an external software (ImageMagick in this example)?

Comment: The solution mentioned in the linked post uses matplotlib's animation module to create the gifs. But this also only works via ImageMagick. And you'd have less options.

Comment: Note that ImageMagick is a highly optimized and highly flexible open source package. Unfortunately, it hasn't a good python binding. But the command line is quite easy to use.  Inside Python, you could do a system call with `import io; system('convert ....')`. Note that gifs are a very old format with only 256 colors and many trickery to compress animations. All the frames are needed together to create the gif.

Comment: Hi, JohanC. Thanks for the help! I'm working on a server and they don't have ImageMagick installed (on my laptop it worked though). That's why I asked. I have of course seen many examples of animations using matplotlib. But I still cannot get something working with heatmaps. Those codes with a init() and update() function look confusing to me and I cannot translate that to using the heatmaps like in the question code.

Comment: You'd need a backend such as ImageMagick or ffmeg to create an animation file. Most web-services have both installed standardly, as they are used very frequently. ImageMagick is used for example when creating thumbnails. I think the "confusing" matplotlib's animation module won't save an animation file if you don't have ImageMagick nor ffmpeg installed.